# Author year style

Tags: bibliographies, packages

Please I am writing a journal paper. The journal requires the following:

1. Citation, should be [numbers].
2. Bibliography, should be like this:
   "Gamelin FX, Baquet G, Berthoin S, Thevenet D, Nourry C, Nottin S, Bosquet L (2009) Effect of high intensity intermittent training on heart rate variability in prepubescent children. Eur J Appl Physiol 105:731-738."
3. The first reference that appears in the article takes the priority in the bibliography "non alphabetically".

Please I tried many packages and styles, but non of them gave me these requirement.

For example, I have used the following

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\smartqed  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}\sloppy

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{document}
```

So, I have got:

> 1. Abouel Nasr, E. S. and Kamrani, A. K. [2006], `A new methodology for extracting manufacturing features from CAD system', Computers and
>      Industrial Engineering 51(3), 389-415.

Also, the bibliography appeared in alphabetically style, which is something I don't want.

Some of the error messages I got:

[image]

Shortend code of `bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{146}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}

\bibitem[{Fu(1977)}]{Fu1977}
Fu KS (1977) {Introduction to Syntactic Pattern Recognition}, Springer Berlin
  Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, pp 1--30. \doi{10.1007/978-3-642-66438-0_1}




\bibitem[{Halevi and Weill(1995)}]{Halevi1995}
Halevi G, Weill RD (1995) {Computer-aided process planning (CAPP)}, Springer
  Netherlands, Dordrecht, pp 317--332. \doi{10.1007/978-94-011-1250-5_15}


\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: It's the default with `biblatex` (`numeric`  style), but this has nothing to do with the author-year style.

Comment: @Bernard Please, could you give me more details?!

Comment: Yes, but you should post a minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I have used                           \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}                               \bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyl{agsm}

Comment: The `natbib` package helps to manage citation call-outs. It's not involved in the formatting of the bibliographic entries, though.

Comment: @Bernard I have edited my question and added an example. Thank you.

Comment: We would need a full (short) code beginning with `\documentclass` and ending in `end{document}`  demonstrating the problem, and a small .bib file.

Comment: @Bernard I have added a full (short) code as you asked, but unfortunately I'm not sure how I can attach a .bib file here. As you noticed, I am totally new for these things.

Comment: Just copy-paste the `.bib` file (just enough entries to demonstrate the issue) the way you did the `.tex` file. For your MWE to demonstrate the problem, you are going to need to cite something - or a couple of somethings - in your document, too.

Comment: Springer has its own bibliography styles you can use. Ask the editors for advice which one is suitable.

Comment: @Johannes_B  I already used Springer style, but the journal asked me to use the style that appears in their site. However, they don't tell what is the name of this style, they just put an example, which is the same one that I added in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this link](http://www.springer.com/engineering/industrial+management/journal/170?detailsPage=pltci_3389378) you find informations about References (open section `References`) and look at the end of the text you find:

> Authors preparing their manuscript in LaTeX can use the    bibtex file
>   `spbasic.bst` which is included in Springer’s LaTeX    macro
>   package.

That means you can use bibliography style `spbasic` regardless the result. It is the work of the journal to get the bibliography for publishing in the layout they need.

Because you gave us no bib file, only the condent of the `*.bbl` file, I created one bib entry from your informations:

```
@article{Halevi,
  author    = {Halevi, G and Weill, RD},
  title     = {Computer-aided process planning},
  journal   = {CAPP},
  pages     = {317--332},
  year      = {1995},
  DOI       = {10.1007/978-94-011-1250-5_15},
}
```

This bib entry contains in the doi an `_`, which gives you the error "missing $ inserted" because it is missinterpreted to be math mode ...

This errors goes away after insertion of line

```
\usepackage{url}
```

or

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

to your preamble.

In the following compiling MWE I added the bib file with package `filecontents`.  Please see that I deleted all not used packages for the issue. Please see that package `caption` and `subcaption` are not able to work together with class `svjour3`.

So the MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@article{Halevi,
  author    = {Halevi, G and Weill, RD},
  title     = {Computer-aided process planning},
  journal   = {CAPP},
  pages     = {317--332},
  year      = {1995},
  DOI       = {10.1007/978-94-011-1250-5_15},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\smartqed  

%%\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % causes warning, do not use!
%%\usepackage{subcaption} % causes warning, do not use with class svjour3!
\usepackage{url} % <====================================================
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}
\sloppy

\nocite{*} or
text \cite{einstein} text

\bibliographystyle{spbasic} % agsm spbasic spmpsci spphys plainnat unsrtnat
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

gives you the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I am so thankful for you. Please try to be patient with me because I am really stuck. So, I already use the "Springer’s LaTeX macro package". I have changed the bibliography style from agsm to spbasic as you said, and this is the only thing that I changed, but unfortunately I got many errors (the code didn't compile). Please what should I do? Please notice that I have no experience with Latex. Again, I am so thankful for the help that you give.

Comment: I have added two bib entrys giving errors to my question. Hopefully I added them in the right way. Many thanks again

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "entrys", however I have copied the starting lines from the library.bib and added them to my question.

Comment: I found the reason of the errors. It's actually the underscores. I used \_ instead, and this is solved the issue. But there is one last thing please. The references appears in alphabetically, and that effects the numbering in the text. The first reference in the text should be [1] in the bibliography. Please how can I do that?

Comment: I am really thankful for all the help that you gave.